# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : action parameter not binding

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, I am trying to bind action parameters on HTTP `POST` requests using the `FromBody` attribute.

However, it's not binding the value for it and is always null.
Here is my code for the same.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public string RegisterUser([FromBody] string FirstName, [FromBody] string LastName)
{
    return($"{FirstName} {LastName}")
}
```

Ajax request:

```
var data = {
              FirstName: "Krunal",
              LastName: "Zala"
           }
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Login/RegisterUser",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function (result) {
       console.log(result.d);
   },
   error: function (result) {
       console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action can have only one [FromBody] attribute. So you will have to create a model to get data

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

after this your action should be

```
public string RegisterUser([FromBody] Person person)
{
 return ($"{person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
}
```

ajax

```
.....
 success: function (result) {
       console.log(result);
   },
....
```

Comment: Thank you @Serge. I just read it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1